# local declaration of 'myViewController' hides instance veriable

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactionsheet, uiactionsheetdelegate

In the action sheet delegate method im modaling to another view based on the button index, this is the method:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        NSLog(@"first button was pressed");
    } else if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        MyViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:myViewController];
        [self.navigationController presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

im getting the error next to the nevigationConroller declaration, does someone knows what is the problem?

im declaring MyViewController in the .h class of this class..

thanks

Comment: Search on the error. This has been covered many times. Start by looking at the Related questions to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class that contains your `actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:` method has an ivar named `myViewController`. You have created a local variable *also* named `myViewController`. Your Xcode project has been told to treat this as an error instead of just a warning. Change your local variable name.

```
MyViewController *myVC = [[MyViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:myVC];
[self.navigationController presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```